# Can someone identify what these files are procmon is showing? Trying to fix waking external drives

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sleep, procmon

So ive gone through the ringer trying to stop my external drives from being up more than not.  They're waking over and over if they even get a chance to spin down.

TortoiseSVNCache was one culpprit.  User Assist for frequently accessed files was another.

I'm now left with this guy.

[image]

The weirdest part is that drive, its a plex media drive.  So is Q but its not seeing all those odd points being accessed.

Can someone tell me what they are and how to make it stop?

EDIT:  Oh boy.  ive pared this down much further.   I watched these fire off as all 4 of my externals woke up sequentially.  These are definitely the culprit.  Anyone able to identify?  Whatever is causing $Mft and $Logfile  I cant even get 15m of sleep out of my drives.

Theyre not indexed, i have background services disabled in windows10.  I turned off frequently used apps in the start menu.   I disabled tsvncache and tgitcache from all but my system drive.   Windows is impossible.

[image]

Comment: $Extend is a folder created by Windows, I have seen these alot using a recovery software I have had since Windows XP. I see them mostly on NTFS hard disks. Svchost is just reading and writing to the files. This $Extend folder is where __Chkdsk__ finds the logs $UsnJrnl  (USN Journal),  $Reparse, __$ObjId__ and $Quota among others. "The USN Journal (Update Sequence Number Journal), or Change Journal, is a feature of NTFS which maintains a record of changes made to the volume."-Wikipedia.org https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal

Comment: It's a folder created by _NTFS_, because NTFS was designed to store its internal metadata within actual files... (It inherited that from OpenVMS Files-11.) You'll get the same $files and $Extend folder on any NTFS volume whether you're using Windows or not.

Comment: I do use macrium reflect, but i still cant understand why (and ive let procmon run for hours) its wanting to harass that drive and none of the others.

will dig deeper

Answer (score 1):

All those events are caused by a single service host process, and likely by a single service running in that process. Double clicking on any of the event lines should
open the event properties dialog, and the stack tab therein will contain information about which executable module (.exe or .dll file) is causing the event. It shouldn't be too hard to correlate the module name to a specific service running in Windows. You may be able to simply disable that service, although doing so could conceivably have unwanted consequences.